# Update attribute only when value is not nil

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have simple sql statement:

```
UPDATE people 
SET (updated_at, first_name, last_name, email) = 
    (now(), r.first_name, r.last_name, r.email) 
WHERE id = r.p_id;
```

I want to set the `email` value only when `r.email` is `not nil`.

Is there any way to do it in one query?

Comment: You don't have no r table in there.

Comment: This query is from the biggest one. Do not suggest that there is no r table here.

Comment: `WHERE email is not NULL;` ?

Comment: But with your code it will not update people record when emails is null. I want to update updated_at, first_name, last_name always and update email only if is not blank.

Comment: Your question lacks clarity and your script (like Jakub said) does not contain a `r` table. The more I read your comments, the more it gets confusing. I suggest you update your question and script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is part of another query

You need to add a conditional. Depending on which DBMS (PostgreSQL, MySQL) you will need different solutions.

---

### PostgreSQL

You'll need **COALESCE**.
The `COALESCE` function returns the first of its arguments that is not null.

```
UPDATE people
SET (updated_at, first_name, last_name, email) = (now(), r.first_name, r.last_name, 
    (COALESCE (r.email, people.email)) 
FROM people, r
WHERE people.id = r.p_id
```

---

### MySQL

You'll need an **IF** condition:

```
IF (r.email IS NULL, people.email, r.email)
```

So the query you need to perform should be similar to:

```
UPDATE people
SET (updated_at, first_name, last_name, email) = (now(), r.first_name, r.last_name, 
    (IF (r.email IS NULL, people.email, r.email)) 
FROM people, r
WHERE people.id = r.p_id
```

Comment: Thank's for reply. I've used your query to test in sql console but it doesnt work:(

UPDATE people 
SET (email) = (('example@email.com' OR people.email)) 
WHERE id = 618044;

returns:
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type boolean: "example@email.com"
LINE 2: SET (email) = (('example@email.com' OR people.email))

Comment: Mateusz Urbański you're right, in this case you'll probably need an IF condition. Let me know if that works instead

Comment: There is no `IF` in (standard) SQL - and definitely not in Postgres

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name true, it's in MySQL only. In Postgres it's another solution

Comment: This query:
UPDATE people
SET (email) = ((IF (people.email IS NULL, people.email, 'asd@o2.pl')))
WHERE id = 618044;

returns me this:

ERROR:  function if(boolean, character varying, unknown) does not exist
LINE 2: SET (email) = ((IF (people.email IS NULL, people.email, 'asd...
                        ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: which DBMS are you using? MySQL, Postgres?

Comment: Did you try the solution for PostgresSQL above?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84664/discussion-between-raviolicode-and-mateusz-urbanski).

Comment: Why the MySQL solution if the question was tagged `postgresql` right from the start?

Comment: Because I didn't see the `postgres` tag before :(